# npm not found but installed from the shell script file in Dockerfile

Tags: docker, dockerfile, shell-script, bash, npm

I have a following Dockerfile:

```
FROM ubuntu:18.04

RUN mkdir app && cd app
WORKDIR app/

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
    software-properties-common \
    curl \
    sudo \
    && curl -O https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/latest/prereqs-ubuntu.sh \
    && chmod u+x prereqs-ubuntu.sh \
    && ./prereqs-ubuntu.sh \
    && npm install -g \ # this line failed
    && yo \
       composer-cli@0.20 \
       composer-rest-server@0.20 \
       generator-hyperledger-composer@0.20 \
       composer-playground@0.20

    CMD /bin/bash
```

The `prereqs-ubuntu.sh` is from https://github.com/hyperledger/composer/blob/master/packages/composer-website/jekylldocs/prereqs-ubuntu.sh.

However, it says `/bin/sh: 1: npm: not found` on the line `npm install -g` when I try to build the image. But `npm` is installed when running `prereqs-ubuntu.sh` already and can be ran successfully at the end of the file (`npm --version`).

Also, when I remove the `npm-install` part from the Dockerfile (shown below) and do `docker run --name test -it myimage` to see if `npm` is installed, but it is installed.

```
FROM ubuntu:18.04

RUN mkdir app && cd app
WORKDIR app/

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
    software-properties-common \
    curl \
    sudo \
    && curl -O https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/latest/prereqs-ubuntu.sh \
    && chmod u+x prereqs-ubuntu.sh \
    && ./prereqs-ubuntu.sh \

    CMD /bin/bash
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is that `prereqs-ubuntu.sh` uses `bash` to install the `npm`. While the `RUN` directive uses `sh` to run the commands.

Where is the npm installed

```
root@2cd4a6af90f4:/app# type npm
npm is /root/.nvm/versions/node/v8.16.0/bin/npm
```

The `PATH` for the `RUN` directive

```
# echo $PATH
/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin
```

Comment: Thanks but how does one fix this? I am on MacOS trying to run my Node app on docker.